# How to select between two LOV's based on some condition in Oracle form 6i

Tags: oracleforms, lov

I am developing a form in Oracle Apps (Oracle Form 6i). I need to provide LOV for a particular field, Say "size" and also I want to have multiple LOV which can be selected by some condition.

For example:

I have two field : "Liveries_Category" and "Size"
Now if I select "Raincoat" in "Liveries_Category" then the "size" field should display the LOV related to Raincoat size (Like: L, M, Ex-L etc.)

And if I select "Shoe" in "Liveries_Category" then the "size" field should display the LOV related to Shoe size (Like: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc.)

So please advise me, how will I going to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a dynamic record group i.e. with a query and take the condition as an input to that query.

For example:

Select "some value" from "table" where condition = :Block_name.field name

for my Question it would be: Select size from "table" where condition = :Block name.liveries_category

when liveries_category is Raincoat it will going to return the Raincoat Size and for Shoe it will return shoe size